# Create dropdown attribute containing country codes, magento

Tags: magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

i have created a dropdown attribute in magento which shows a list of all countries. I did this by creating a dropdown attribute in the backend then I used SQLyog to change it's source model to `catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture`. Now it shows the list of countries. I would like to create a new dropdown attribute which will show the list of all country codes(in two-letter format)...

Comment: see this link http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/list-countries-for-drop-down-in-magento.html

Comment: or there's a sample dropdown in this link http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

Comment: I don't know which file to put those codes on...

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a custom source model and assign it to your new attribute. To achieve this in your module create an install/upgrade script. Make sure that the setup model extends either `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup`, e.g.:

```
       <resources>
            <yourpackage_yourmodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>YourPackage_YourModule</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </yourpackage_yourmodule_setup>
        </resources>
```

In the install script create an attribute with the source model property set to your custom class:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$applyTo = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE
);

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'custom_countries', 
    array(
        'group'             => 'General',
        'type'              => 'int',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Custom Countries',
        'input'             => 'select',
        'source'            => 'yourpackage_yourmodule/product_attribute_source_custom',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
        'apply_to'          => implode(',',$applyTo)
    )
);

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_countries', 'backend_model', '');

$installer->endSetup();
```

In your module's Model folder create a directory structure `Product/Attribute/Source` and place a file `Custom.php` there - this is where you will put your custom source model in.

Into the file `YourPackage/YourModule/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Custom.php` put a class with the following definition.

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Custom
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture
{
```

Add a function override into it, which swaps the option labels' country names with country codes:

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $options = parent::getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
            $options[$key] = array('value' => $option['value'], 'label' => $option['value']);
        }
        return $options;
    }
```

Done.